# Lazyloading with intersection observer when sorting

Tags: lazy-loading, svelte

I output a bunch of images, each wrapped in an intersection observer using svelte-intersection-observer:

```
<script>
import IntersectionObserver from "svelte-intersection-observer";
let elements = {};
let intersects = {};
export let posts;
</script>

<section id="posts">
  {#each posts as p}
      <IntersectionObserver
      once
      element={elements[p]}
      bind:intersecting={intersects[p]}
      >
        <div>
            <img
              bind:this={elements[p]}
              src={intersects[p] ?
              `/${p}/thumb.jpg`
              :
              'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII='}
            loading="lazy"
            alt=""
            width="350"
            height="150"
            />
        </div>
      </IntersectionObserver>
    {/if}
  {/each}
</section>
```

On the page, I also offer links to sort the posts array (e.g., random order, by id ascending/descending).

The intersection observer works well on first page load and when scrolling.

But as soon as the order of the posts array is changed (on the fly, simply by sorting the array), the intersect event is not fired for those images that are now in the viewport.
When I scroll down, images are loaded. But the ones that are at the top are not.

Answer (score -1):

Interesting. I was able to solve this with a keyed each loop:

```
{#each posts as p (p)}
  <IntersectionObserver ... />
{/each}
```